# grails: create entry in database from controller

Tags: database, grails

I have two domain classes, A and B.
B class belongs to A class. I want that, when A object is created, a B object is automatically created too and added into the related db table (with the id value of the A object).
Is it possible? How can I do it?

I've tried doing the following (in A controller):

```
def b = new B();

    b.a = aInstance;

    if(!b.save(flush: true)){
        flash.message = "error"
        return
    }
```

but `b.save()` always fails...

EDIT:
it seems that the problem is that some field is required. the class B is as follows:

```
class B {

int field1;
int field2;
String field3;

static belongsTo = [anstances:A]
static constraints = {
}
```

}

Why do the fields `field1` and `field2` are required?

EDIT2:
I've changed type of int fields to String. Now they are not required, but save() returns null and i see the "error" label

Comment: What do you mean by "always fails"?  Are there validation errors, stacktrace, what?

Comment: I've noticed that the problem is about validation...I edit the question

Comment: Either debug using your IDE or do a println(b.errors) and make sure you don't have any other validation issues.

Comment: "I've changed type of int fields to String. Now they are not required" - they _are_ still required unless you've specifically said otherwise in your `constraints` block - `field1 nullable:true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your edit, the saving issue is because you haven't specified a constraint on your properties and fields are nullable: false by default.  From the [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/Usage.html):

> nullable: Allows a property to be set to null - **defaults to false**.

Comment: Problem is that database table is not updated after reloading the application